# SQL return Same Date, UID, Different States

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a Tableau Custom SQL from a large data source that will return all records of the same date, same UID, with different states.  As shown below:

## Input:

```
UID     ST  DOS
11111   WI  1/1/2018
11111   WI  1/1/2018
11111   MN  1/1/2018
11111   CO  1/31/2018
```

## Desired Output:

```
UID     ST  DOS
11111   WI  1/1/2018
11111   MN  1/1/2018
```

I know this does not work but something along this line.  Thank you for your help in advance.

```
Select UID, DOS, ST
from DATA.TABLE2
Where UID in ('11111') and DOS = DOS and ST >('2')
```

Comment: Why does it return the WI record only once?  You claim you want *all* records.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does what the data suggests:

```
select distinct t2.UID, t2.DOS, t2.ST
from DATA.TABLE2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from data.table2 tt2
              where tt2.uid = t2.uid and
                    tt2.dos = t2.dos and
                    tt2.st <> t2.st
             );
```

Your question doesn't actually suggest removing duplicates, so if you want the duplicates, remove the `distinct`.

Comment: I believe this will do the trick, (it is still running) is there a way I can limit the date span using a lookback?  e.g.,  Where DOS > date_trunc('month',date(current_date - cast('24 month' as interval)))

Comment: @Amanda . . . Of course.  You can put that condition in the outer `where` (I would put it before the `exists`).

Answer (score 0):

You want `subquery` here :

```
select t.*
from DATA.TABLE2 t
where DOS = (select min(t1.DOS) from DATA.TABLE2 t1 where t1.UID = t.UID);
```